# Proof of uniformly continuous of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-continuity

> $f:(a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous. $f'(x)$ exists on $(a,b)$ and  $\lim_{x \rightarrow a+}f'(x)$ exists. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b]$

My thoughts:
If we can define $f(a)$ such that $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ we are done. But we only know $\lim_{x \rightarrow a+}f'(x)$ exists. How can we define $f(a)$ out of $f'(a)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the limit $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)$ exists, there is some $c\in(a,b]$ such that $f'|_{(a,c]}$ is bounded, which implies that $f|_{(a,c]}$ is uniformly continuous. And si $[c,b]$ is a closed and bounded interval and $f$ is coninuous, $f|-{[c,b]}$ is also uniformly continuous.

Therefore, $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: I see. Didn't know that bounded derivative implies uniformly continuous but it can be proved by mean value theorem.    Thank you very much Jose!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Carlos. Please help me out.1) Need to show that f is bounded on (a,b] to extend countinuosly to [a,b].2) Since $f' \rightarrow a^+$ exists there is a c , s.t. f' on  [a,c] is bounded. Implies f is bounded on [a,b]. Can be extended continously on [a,b], hence uniformly continuous on [a,b]. Is this OK?Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.